# Implicit List of All Build Targets in SCONS?

Tags: c++, scons

I have an scons project that force includes several header files as a compiler flag.

```
# Forced include files passed directly to the compiler
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['/FIinclude.h'])
```

These files are not included by any files in the project. I need to add an explicit dependency for them.

```
forced_include_headers = ['include.h']

# Trying to add an explicit dependency for each build target
for object in BUILD_TARGETS:
  env.Depends(object, forced_include_headers)
```

The problem I'm running into is that `BUILD_TARGETS` list is empty. It seems to only contain things passed from `COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS` or `DEFAULT_TARGETS`. All of the targets in our project are built implicitly. We do not make use of `env.Default`, etc. Is there a way to get the implicit target list, or do I have to manually build it? I noticed that `TARGETS` is reserved and does not seem to contain what I want either.

I can add an `env.Depends(target, forced_include_headers)` for all of the targets in their respective SConscript files, but the project is quite large.

Comment: I ended up solving this by calling a psuedo-builder for every target in the project (needed to do this anyway). The dependency is added in the call to the psuedo-builder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to solve the problem (in fact, I think the idea of creating a pseudo-builder works better), but this code will return a list of `Object` targets:

```
# Typical SConstruct / SConscript
env = Environment()
env.Program('foo.c')
lib = env.SharedLibrary('bar.c')
env.Program('foo2.c', LIBS=[lib])
SConscript('subdir/SConscript', exports={'env':env})

# Get a list of all Object targets
def get_all_targets(env, node='.'):
    def get_all_targets_iter(env, node):
        if node.has_builder() and node.get_builder().get_name(env) in ('Object', 'SharedObject'):
            yield node
        for kid in node.all_children():
            for kid in get_all_targets(env, kid):
                yield kid
    node = env.arg2nodes(node, env.fs.Entry)[0]
    return list(get_all_targets_iter(env, node))

# Force them all to depend upon some header
env.Depends(get_all_targets(env), 'site_wide.h')
```